# Where are the errors in this convergence proof?

Tags: real-analysis

The following proof is wrong, and I'm not 100% sure why.

---

$a_n$ is a sequence s.t. $|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| < \frac{1}{n}$. Determine whether $a_n$ converges.

We want to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N: n, m > N \implies |a_m - a_n| < \epsilon$.

WLOG, let $m \geq n$.

Let $k = m - n$, so that $n + k = m$.

Note that $\lim |a_{n+1} - a_{n}| = 0$.

$|a_m - a_n|$

$= |a_{n+k} - a_n|$

$= |(a_{n+k} - a_{n+k-1}) + (a_{n+k-1} - a_{n+k-2}) + \ldots + (a_{n+1} - a_n)|$

$\leq |a_{n+k} - a_{n+k-1}| + |a_{n+k-1} - a_{n+k-2}| + \ldots + |a_{n+1} - a_n|$

Therefore:

$\lim |a_{m} - a_n|$

$\leq \lim(|a_{n+k} - a_{n+k-1}| + |a_{n+k-1} - a_{n+k-2}| + \ldots + |a_{n+1} - a_n|)$ (1)

$= \lim |a_{n+k} - a_{n+k-1}| + \lim |a_{n+k-1} - a_{n+k-2}| + \ldots + \lim |a_{n+1} - a_n|$ (2)

$= 0 + 0  + \ldots + 0$ (3)

$= 0$

So $|a_{m} - a_n|$ converges to 0, meaning $a_n$ is Cauchy, and hence converges.

---

My guess is, this proof doesn't work because you can't always go from (1) to (2), but (2) to (3) could also be suspect.

I'd like to hear thoughts from a more experienced mathematician.

Comment: Where's your $N$?

Comment: Note that $\log(n+1)-\log(n) = \log(1+\frac{1}{n}) < \frac{1}{n},$ so it isn't just that the proof is wrong: the statement isn't true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is the equals-sign at the beginning of line (2). You're presumably thinking of the principle "the limit of a sum equals the sum of the limits (provided the latter exists)." But this principle is correct only when the number of summands is fixed.  In your situation, the number $k$ of summands is not fixed, and so the principle does not apply.

For a simpler example of this situation, consider the sum $\frac1n+\frac1n+\cdots+\frac1n$, where there are $n$ summands. So this sum is simply $1$. The limit of the sum as $n\to\infty$ is therefore also $1$. Yet each of the summands $\frac1n$ approaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that $$\log(n+1)-\log(n) = \log(1+\frac{1}{n}) < \frac{1}{n},$$ so it isn't just that the proof is wrong: the statement isn't true.

The problem with the proof is with your order of limits. To show it's Cauchy, you need to show for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that for *any* $m,n >N,$ $|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon.$ In your argument, you show (indirectly) that you can find an $N$ for a given $k$ such that $m=n+k,n,$ but you don't show that you can find one $N$ that works for all $n,m.$

In order to iterate the small gap between $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ into a small gap between $a_{n+k} $ and $a_n$ you need to add up $k$ gaps, all of which go like $\frac{1}{n+k}.$ Since $\sum_{k} \frac{1}{n+k}$ does not converge, there is no guarantee that the size of the gap $|a_{n+k}-a_n|$ can be controlled for arbitrarily large $k$. In other words, $$ \infty = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k} \ne \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+k} = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=a_n+\dfrac{1}{n+1}$. Then $a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\dfrac1{n+1}$.

Is such $(a_n)$ convergent?

What is (your) $|a_{n+k} - a_{n+k-1}| + |a_{n+k-1} - a_{n+k-2}| + \ldots + |a_{n+1} - a_n|$ for this sequence?